# JIT compiler - compiler choosing options

Tags: java, jvm, jit

On 64 bit linux, with java8, when running `java` command, it seems all the 3 options `-client` / `-server` / `-d64` are using the 64-bit server compiler.

**The questions are:** (*for 64bit linux with java8*)

- Since `-client` and `-server` use the same compiler, does it makes any difference to specify one of the 2 options?
- For a long running java daemon program, is it preferred to use `-server` together with `-XX:+TieredCompilation` or without it, when during the startup time it's ok to be a little slow.

Comment: You are mistaken. `-client` and `-server` select different JVMs.

Comment: @EJP I think the 2 options choose different JIT compiler, which compile bytecode to machine code, which is in running time, and thus result in 2 type of java process with different behavior. Since a jvm is just a java process, so, it's ok for you to say that they choose different jvms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the file `jre/lib/amd64/jvm.cfg`. You'll likely see the lines

```
-server KNOWN
-client IGNORE
```

This means that `-client` option is ignored. `-server` also does nothing, since JDK 8 for x64 has only one JVM that includes both C1 and C2 compilers, and the tiered compilation is on by default.

> with -XX:+TieredCompilation or without it

Does not matter, because this option is on by default. The [advanced compilation policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35601841/how-does-the-jvm-decided-to-jit-compile-a-method-categorize-a-method-as-hot/35614237#35614237) works fine for both client-grade and server-grade applications. There is no usually need to turn it off manually.

Comment: Cool, that makes things easier.