# Unclear intrinsic behaviour in Java9

Tags: java, jvm, virtual-machine, jvm-arguments, java-9

Suppose I have this code (it really does not matter I think, but just in case here it is):

```
public class AtomicJDK9 {

     static AtomicInteger ai = new AtomicInteger(0);

     public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 30_000; ++i) {
           sum += atomicIncrement();
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
     }

     public static int atomicIncrement() {
         ai.getAndAdd(12);
         return ai.get();
     }
}
```

And here is how I am invoking it (using java-9):

```
 java -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions 
      -XX:-TieredCompilation  
      -XX:+PrintIntrinsics  
      AtomicJDK9
```

What I am trying to find out is what methods were replaced by intrinsic code. The first one that is hit (inside Unsafe):

```
      @HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate
      public final int getAndAddInt(Object o, long offset, int delta) {
         int v;
         do {
            v = getIntVolatile(o, offset);
         } while (!weakCompareAndSwapIntVolatile(o, offset, v, v + delta));
         return v;
      }
```

And this method is indeed present in the output of the above invocation:

```
 @ 8   jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe::getAndAddInt (27 bytes)   (intrinsic)
```

But, the entire output is weird (for me that is):

```
 @ 8   jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe::getAndAddInt (27 bytes)   (intrinsic)
 @ 3   jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe::getIntVolatile (0 bytes)   (intrinsic)
 @ 18  jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe::weakCompareAndSwapIntVolatile (11 bytes)   (intrinsic)
 @ 7   jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe::compareAndSwapInt (0 bytes)   (intrinsic)
 @ 8   jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe::getAndAddInt (27 bytes)   (intrinsic)
```

Why is the **getAndAddInt** present twice in the output?

Also if getAndAddInt is indeed replaced by an intrinsic call, why is there a need to replace *all other intrinsic methods down the call stack*l they will not be used anymore. I do assume it's as simple as the stack of method calls is traversed from the bottom.

Comment: maybe adding `+PrintCompilation` (or whatever the new unified logging equivalent is) and shed light on the context.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to illustrate the compiler logic I ran JVM with the following arguments.

```
    -XX:-TieredCompilation -XX:CICompilerCount=1
    -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintCompilation -XX:+PrintInlining
```

And that's what it prints.

```
337   29   java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger::getAndAdd (12 bytes)
              @ 8   jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe::getAndAddInt (27 bytes)   (intrinsic)
337   30   jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe::getAndAddInt (27 bytes)
              @ 3   jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe::getIntVolatile (0 bytes)   (intrinsic)
              @ 18   jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe::weakCompareAndSwapIntVolatile (11 bytes)   (intrinsic)
338   32   jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe::weakCompareAndSwapIntVolatile (11 bytes)
              @ 7   jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe::compareAndSwapInt (0 bytes)   (intrinsic)
339   33   AtomicJDK9::atomicIncrement (16 bytes)
              @ 5   java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger::getAndAdd (12 bytes)   inline (hot)
                @ 8   jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe::getAndAddInt (27 bytes)   (intrinsic)
              @ 12   java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger::get (5 bytes)   accessor
```

- Methods are intrinsics only for compiler, but not for interpreter.
- Every method starts in interpreter until it is [considered hot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35601841/how-does-the-jvm-decided-to-jit-compile-a-method-categorize-a-method-as-hot/35614237#35614237).
- `AtomicInteger.getAndAdd` is called not only from your code, but from common JDK code, too.
- That is, `AtomicInteger.getAndAdd` reaches invocation threshold a little bit earlier than your `AtomicJDK9.atomicIncrement`. Then `getAndAdd` is submitted to compilation queue, and that's where the first intrinsic printout comes from.
- HotSpot JVM compiles methods in background. While a method is being compiled, the execution continues in interpreter.
- While `AtomicInteger.getAndAdd` is interpreted, `Unsafe.getAndAddInt` and `Unsafe.weakCompareAndSwapIntVolatile` methods also reach invocation threshold and begin compilation. The next 3 intrinsics are printed while compiling these `Unsafe` methods.
- Finally, `AtomicJDK9.atomicIncrement` also reaches invocation threashold and begin compilation. The last intrinsic printout corresponds to your method.