# JIT recompiles to do fast Throw after more iterations if stacktrace is of even length

Tags: java, jvm, jit

The following code,

```
public class TestFastThrow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count = 0;
        int exceptionStackTraceSize = 0;
        Exception exception = null;
        do {
            try {
                throwsNPE(1);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                exception = e;
                if (exception.getStackTrace().length != 0) {
                    exceptionStackTraceSize = exception.getStackTrace().length;
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        while (exception.getStackTrace().length != 0);
        System.out.println("Iterations to fastThrow :" + count + ", StackTraceSize :" + exceptionStackTraceSize);
    }

    static void throwsNPE(int callStackLength) {
        throwsNPE(callStackLength, 0);
    }

    static void throwsNPE(int callStackLength, int count) {
        if (count == callStackLength) {
            ((Object) null).getClass();
        }
        else {
            throwsNPE(callStackLength, count + 1);
        }
    }

}
```

gives the following output after running multiple times,

```
Iterations to fastThrow :5517, StackTraceSize :4
Iterations to fastThrow :2825, StackTraceSize :5
Iterations to fastThrow :471033, StackTraceSize :6
Iterations to fastThrow :1731, StackTraceSize :7
Iterations to fastThrow :157094, StackTraceSize :10
.
.
.
Iterations to fastThrow :64587, StackTraceSize :20
Iterations to fastThrow :578, StackTraceSize :29
```

VM details

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.5+10-LTS) for bsd-amd64 JRE (11.0.5+10-LTS)
-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+TraceClassLoading -XX:+LogCompilation -XX:+PrintAssembly
```

What was surprising is why does the JIT take much more iterations to optimize if the stack trace is of even length?

I enabled JIT Logs and analysed via jitwatch, but couldn't see anything helpful, just that the timeline of when the C1 and C2 compilation seems to be happening later for the even size stacktraces.

Time line is something like this, (looking at when `java.lang.Throwable.getStackTrace()` is compiled)

```
| StackSize     | 10    | 11    |
|---------------|-------|-------|
| Queued for C1 | 1.099 | 1.012 |
| C1            | 1.318 | 1.162 |
| Queued for C2 | 1.446 | 1.192 |
| C2            | 1.495 | 1.325 |
```

Why exactly is this happening? And what heuristics does the JIT use for fast throw?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This effect is a result of tricky [tiered compilation and inlining policy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35614237/3448419).

Let me explain on the simplified example:

```java
public class TestFastThrow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int iteration = 0; ; iteration++) {
            try {
                throwsNPE(2);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (e.getStackTrace().length == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Iterations to fastThrow: " + iteration);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static void throwsNPE(int depth) {
        if (depth <= 1) {
            ((Object) null).getClass();
        }
        throwsNPE(depth - 1);
    }
}
```

For simplicity, I'll exclude all methods from compilation, except `throwsNPE`.

```
-XX:CompileCommand=compileonly,TestFastThrow::throwsNPE -XX:+PrintCompilation
```

1. HotSpot uses Tiered Compilation by default. Here `throwsNPE` is first compiled at tier 3 (C1 with profiling). Profiling in C1 makes possible to recompile the method later by C2.
2. `OmitStackTraceInFastThrow` optimization works only in C2 compiled code. So, the sooner the code is compiled by C2 - the less iterations will pass before the loop finishes.
3. How profiling in C1-compiled code works: the counter is incremented on every method invocation and on every backward branch (however, there are no backward branches in `throwsNPE` method). When the counter reaches certain configurable threshold, JVM compilation policy decides whether current method needs to be recompiled.
4. `throwsNPE` is a recursive method. HotSpot can inline recursive calls up to `-XX:MaxRecursiveInlineLevel` (default value is 1).
5. The frequency how often C1 compiled code calls back to JVM compilation policy, differs for regular invocations vs. inlined invocations. A regular method notifies JVM every 2<sup>10</sup> invocations (`-XX:Tier3InvokeNotifyFreqLog=10`), while the inlined method notifies JVM much more rarely: every 2<sup>20</sup> invocations (`-XX:Tier23InlineeNotifyFreqLog=20`).
6. For the even number of recursive calls, all invocations follow `Tier23InlineeNotifyFreqLog` parameter. When the number of calls is odd, inlining does not work for the last leftover call, and this last invocation follows `Tier3InvokeNotifyFreqLog` parameter.
7. This means, when the call depth is even, `throwsNPE` will be recompiled only after 2<sup>20</sup> calls, i.e. after 2<sup>19</sup> loop iterations. That's exactly what you'll see when you run the above code with `throwNPE(2)`:

   ```
   Iterations to fastThrow: 524536
   ```

   524536 is very close to 2<sup>19</sup> = 524288

   Now, if you run the same application with `-XX:Tier23InlineeNotifyFreqLog=15`, the number of iterations will be close to 2<sup>14</sup> = 16384.

   ```
   Iterations to fastThrow: 16612
   ```
8. Now let's change the code to call `throwsNPE(1)`. The program will finish very quickly, regardless of `Tier23InlineeNotifyFreqLog` value. That's because the different option rules now. But if I rerun the program with `-XX:Tier3InvokeNotifyFreqLog=20`, the loop will finish not earlier than after 2<sup>20</sup> iterations:

   ```
   Iterations to fastThrow: 1048994
   ```

**Summary**

Fast throw optimization applies only to C2-compiled code. Due to one level of inlining (`-XX:MaxRecursiveInlineLevel`), C2 compilation is triggered earlier (after 2<sup>Tier3InvokeNotifyFreqLog</sup> invocations, if the number of recursive calls is odd), or later (after 2<sup>Tier23InlineeNotifyFreqLog</sup> invocations, if all recursive calls are covered by inlining).