# Is there a way of determining JVM CompileThreshold programmatically in java?

Tags: java, performance, jvm, jit

We can determine the compile threshold using these jvm flags `-XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -XX:+PrintFlagsInitial`, but is there a way of determining it programmatically at runtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can get the value, though it is absolutely useless.
With Tiered Compilation (defaut), this flag is [meaningless](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35614237/3448419).

Here is how to get a value of any HotSpot VM flag:

```
HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean mbean = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMXBean(HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean.class);
String value = mbean.getVMOption("CompileThreshold").getValue();
```