# Can I programmatically determine the value of -Xss (default Stack size) in the JVM

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-arguments

I have code that is trying to serialize a very large Java object through Spring into Redis. For most objects, this works fine. For a few very large objects it results in StackOverflowError. I'm trying to figure out if I can tune for this, but I can't find a way to ask the JVM "how big is the default stack"?

Is there some `System.getDefaultStackSize()` or `System.getProperty("Xss")` that I can leverage here?

Comment: It is possible to get the value of `ThreadStackSize` JVM option like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67723382/3448419). How would this help you though?

Comment: @apangin Hmm. `2022-07-18 09:08:50.585  INFO [mbom-service,,,] 7209 --- [           main] a.repositories.redis.MbomRedisRepository :  -Xss is 0` when `.getVMOption("CompilerThreadStackSize")`. This is rather obscure

Comment: You still didn’t say how this value would help you. What are you going to do with that value?

Comment: @Holger Sorry. I'm trying to figure out what the default stacksize is so I can set a larger one to see if I can get my "mega object" to serialize into Redis through Spring's RedisTemplate. Its not looking good. I'm at -Xss3m right now and it takes 6+ minutes, but eventually StackOverflowError

Comment: If you have that option, you can do it regardless of what default stack size you have. But keep in mind that every persistence mechanism has two sides. If you write an object using an extraordinarily large stack, the reading side very likely also needs an extraordinarily large stack…