# Why does Java HotSpot can not optimize array instance after one-time resizing (leads to massive performance loss)?

Tags: java, performance, jvm, jvm-hotspot

## Question

Why is the use of `fBuffer1` in the attached code example (`SELECT_QUICK = true`) **double as fast** as the other variant when `fBuffer2` is resized only once at the beginning (`SELECT_QUICK = false`)?

The code path is absolutely identical but even after 10 minutes the throughput of `fBuffer2` does not increase to this level of `fBuffer1`.

## Background:

We have a generic data processing framework that collects thousands of Java primitive values in different subclasses (one subclass for each primitive type). These values are stored internally in arrays, which we originally sized sufficiently large. To save heap memory, we have now switched these arrays to dynamic resizing (arrays grow only if needed). As expected, this change has massively reduce the heap memory. However, on the other hand the performance has unfortunately degenerated significantly. Our processing jobs now take 2-3 times longer as before (e.g. 6 min instead of 2 min as before).

I have reduced our problem to a minimum working example and attached it. You can choose with `SELECT_QUICK` which buffer should be used. I see the same effect with `jdk-1.8.0_202-x64` as well as with `openjdk-17.0.1-x64`.

#### Buffer 1 (is not resized) shows the following numbers:

```
duration buf1: 8,890.551ms (8.9s)
duration buf1: 8,339.755ms (8.3s)
duration buf1: 8,620.633ms (8.6s)
duration buf1: 8,682.809ms (8.7s)
...
```

#### Buffer 2 (is resized exactly 1 time at the beginning) shows the following numbers:

```
make buffer 2 larger
duration buf2 (resized): 19,542.750ms (19.5s)
duration buf2 (resized): 22,423.529ms (22.4s)
duration buf2 (resized): 22,413.364ms (22.4s)
duration buf2 (resized): 22,219.383ms (22.2s)
...
```

I would really appreciate to get some hints, how I can change the code so that `fBuffer2` (after resizing) works as fast as `fBuffer1`. The other way round (make `fBuffer1` as slow as `fBuffer2`) is pretty easy. ;-) Since this problem is placed in some framework-like component I would prefer to change the code instead of tuning the hotspot (with external arguments). But of course, suggestions in both directions are very welcome.

## Source Code

```
import java.util.Locale;

public final class Collector {

    private static final boolean SELECT_QUICK = true;

    private static final long LOOP_COUNT = 50_000L;
    private static final int VALUE_COUNT = 150_000;
    private static final int BUFFER_LENGTH = 100_000;

    private final Buffer fBuffer = new Buffer();

    public void reset() {fBuffer.reset();}
    public void addValueBuf1(long val) {fBuffer.add1(val);}
    public void addValueBuf2(long val) {fBuffer.add2(val);}

    public static final class Buffer {

        private int fIdx = 0;
        private long[] fBuffer1 = new long[BUFFER_LENGTH * 2];
        private long[] fBuffer2 = new long[BUFFER_LENGTH];

        public void reset() {fIdx = 0;}

        public void add1(long value) {
            ensureRemainingBuf1(1);
            fBuffer1[fIdx++] = value;
        }

        public void add2(long value) {
            ensureRemainingBuf2(1);
            fBuffer2[fIdx++] = value;
        }

        private void ensureRemainingBuf1(int remaining) {
            if (remaining > fBuffer1.length - fIdx) {
                System.out.println("make buffer 1 larger");
                fBuffer1 = new long[(fIdx + remaining) << 1];
            }
        }

        private void ensureRemainingBuf2(int remaining) {
            if (remaining > fBuffer2.length - fIdx) {
                System.out.println("make buffer 2 larger");
                fBuffer2 = new long[(fIdx + remaining) << 1];
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH);
        final Collector collector = new Collector();
        if (SELECT_QUICK) {
            while (true) {
                final long start = System.nanoTime();
                for (long j = 0L; j < LOOP_COUNT; j++) {
                    collector.reset();
                    for (int k = 0; k < VALUE_COUNT; k++) {
                        collector.addValueBuf1(k);
                    }
                }
                final long nanos = System.nanoTime() - start;
                System.out.printf("duration buf1: %1$,.3fms (%2$,.1fs)%n",
                    nanos / 1_000_000d, nanos / 1_000_000_000d);
            }
        } else {
            while (true) {
                final long start = System.nanoTime();
                for (long j = 0L; j < LOOP_COUNT; j++) {
                    collector.reset();
                    for (int k = 0; k < VALUE_COUNT; k++) {
                        collector.addValueBuf2(k);
                    }
                }
                final long nanos = System.nanoTime() - start;
                System.out.printf("duration buf2 (resized): %1$,.3fms (%2$,.1fs)%n",
                    nanos / 1_000_000d, nanos / 1_000_000_000d);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Is `addValueBuf1` the same as `add1`?

Comment: Is it important that `collector.reset()` only resets `fIdx`, not the size of the array?

Comment: Final point, have you considered saving valuable development time and used an existing primitive collection library which guarantees efficient performance?

Comment: The source code is not meant to do something useful. It is just a highly simplified minimal example to reproduce the problem.

The original problem is located in our complex processing pipeline which is an integral part of one of our software components for geospatial traffic processing. Which of course we decided to develop because it doesn't exist like this. :-)

Comment: But apart from the fact that we suffer strongly from this performance degration. The observed effect seems to be weird!? 
Why does HotSpot not optimize the variant with ```fBuffer2``` (even after 1h the throughput is only half as of ```fBuffer1```)?

Comment: @AndyTurner If you pull the code of ```addX()``` one level higher, then both variants perform equally bad. The reset only applies to ```fIdx``` since this can be seen as length indicator for the buffer. Furthermore the buffer itself should only grow and never shrink (except it is explicitly trimmed). It's a similar strategy as performed by ```ArrayList``` for instance.

Comment: My guess is that the code gets heavily inlined, and the compiler can only eliminate array bounds checks when it can prove that the array length is guaranteed to be constant.

Comment: That's a good point. Thus you mean, as long as the array instance is not replaced the JIT compiler may simplify the array access by skipping all further bounds checks.

Comment: I do some further tests and re-assign the ```fBuffer1``` field in line 56 with a variable length, but the massive performance difference is still there. 
```collector.fBuffer.fBuffer1 = new long[BUFFER_LENGTH * 2 + (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() % 2)];```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JIT compilation in HotSpot JVM is 1) based on runtime profile data; 2) uses speculative optimizations.

Once the method is compiled at the maximum optimization level, HotSpot stops profiling this code, so it is never recompiled afterwards, no matter how long the code runs. (The exception is when the method needs to be deoptimized or unloaded, but it's not your case).

In the first case (SELECT_QUICK == true), the condition `remaining > fBuffer1.length - fIdx` is never met, and HotSpot JVM is aware of that from profiling data collected at [lower tiers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35614237/3448419). So it speculatively hoists the check out of the loop, and compiles the loop body with the assumption that array index is always within bounds. After the optimization, the loop is compiled like this (in pseudocode):

```
if (VALUE_COUNT > collector.fBuffer.fBuffer1.length) {
    uncommon_trap();
}
for (int k = 0; k < VALUE_COUNT; k++) {
    collector.fBuffer.fBuffer1[k] = k;  // no bounds check
}
```

In the second case (SELECT_QUICK == false), on the contrary, HotSpot knows that  condition `remaining > fBuffer2.length - fIdx` is *sometimes* met, so it cannot eliminate the check.

Since `fIdx` is not the loop counter, HotSpot is apparently not smart enough to split the loop into two parts (with and without bounds check). However, you can help JIT compiler by splitting the loop manually:

```
for (long j = 0L; j < LOOP_COUNT; j++) {
    collector.reset();

    int fastCount = Math.min(collector.fBuffer.fBuffer2.length, VALUE_COUNT);
    for (int k = 0; k < fastCount; k++) {
        collector.addValueBuf2Fast(k);
    }

    for (int k = fastCount; k < VALUE_COUNT; k++) {
        collector.addValueBuf2(k);
    }
}
```

where `addValueBuf2Fast` inserts a value without bounds check:

```
    public void addValueBuf2Fast(long val) {fBuffer.add2Fast(val);}

    public static final class Buffer {
        ...
        public void add2Fast(long value) {
            fBuffer2[fIdx++] = value;
        }
    }
```

This should dramatically improve performance of the loop:

```
make buffer 2 larger
duration buf2 (resized): 5,537.681ms (5.5s)
duration buf2 (resized): 5,461.519ms (5.5s)
duration buf2 (resized): 5,450.445ms (5.5s)
```

Comment: Thanks for this great answer. I'm sitting here thinking how I can change the code according to your feedback. Unfortunately the submitting loop is just "simulating" the client code, which in fact is not under our control. Sometimes the incoming data is wildy distributed over different buffers and each buffer get a submission of a single value. In other words, there is no "loop" at all. According to your feedback we need a separate hot path for value submission deep to the buffer where the size condition is never triggered. Do you see any other "API" modification ignoring the loop?

Comment: @Mythos In this particular example the large performance difference is a result of the loop optimizations. If there is no similar loop in the production code, I can only conclude that the given benchmark does not reflect the actual behavior of the real code.

Comment: I updated the loop a little to submit a non-constant value, to prevent Hotspot from simply "filling" the array. Even if each value has to be submitted individually, the huge performance difference is still there. 
Maybe we can allow the Hotspot doing a better job by splitting the methods and using an additional count-down threshold that switches between two pathes and only one enables the final length check? Or does it makes sense having some kind of "array-holder" that can be switched between a checked and a non-checked version? I'm just brainstorming ...

Comment: I guess permanently skipping the check but catching the IndexOutOfBoundsException (which in turn triggers the array resize) is a bad idea.

Comment: @Mythos I've pointed out the performance issue with your posted benchmark and suggested a way to speed it up. If this approach cannot be applied to your original problem, it means your benchmark is *not* about the original problem, so any further speculation about this benchmark will be likely wrong.

Comment: I just did some review of the client code where the performance difference heavily occurs. In fact there is always some kind of loop that pushes the data into one (or more) pipelines. So I am very sure that the benchmark matches the problem and you also explained the reason very well. But since we don't have access to the client code (to change the loop), the question is whether we can somehow make the API more "loop-friendly" to assist Hotspot better.

Comment: BTW: The shown benchmark was mainly created by just deleting existing code from our original source code until the problem was minimized. So there was only glue code to be implemented "in addition". My first ideas (I mentioned above Counter, Exception, Holder ...) I have just tried and unfortunately could not achieve any effect. So if you have another starting point, how we can offer Hotspot a fast path on the API, then I would be very happy. In any case, a big thank you for the assistance and quick reaction.