# How is the count of method executions that triggers the omitted exception stack frames calculated in JDK 8?

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception, jvm

JDK version:

```
java version "1.8.0_291"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_291-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.291-b10, mixed mode)
```

If we write the following code:

```java
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int exceptionCount = 0;
        while (true) {
            try {
                Object object = null;
                if (ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(2) == 0) {
                    object = new Object();
                }
                object.hashCode();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(++exceptionCount);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Part of the output is:

```
21123
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Test.main(Test.java:13)
21124
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Test.main(Test.java:13)
21125
java.lang.NullPointerException
21126
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

That is, the stack frame is no longer printed after the exception occurs **21124** times.

Let's make a small change to the above code, pay attention to the parameters of the `nextInt` method:

```java
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int exceptionCount = 0;
        while (true) {
            try {
                Object object = null;
                if (ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt() == 0) {
                    object = new Object();
                }
                object.hashCode();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(++exceptionCount);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Part of the output is:

```
115711
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Test.main(Test.java:13)
115712
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Test.main(Test.java:13)
115713
java.lang.NullPointerException
115714
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

That is, the stack frame is no longer printed after the exception occurs **115712** times.

Now I want to know how the count of executions of this method that triggers the omitted exception stack frame is calculated?

Reference: 
[Release Notes](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/release-notes-introduction.html#:%7E:text=in%20bug%204697804.-,The%20compiler%20in%20the%20server%20VM%20now%20provides%20correct%20stack,.,-Tomcat%20hangs%20after)
[jdk/graphKit.cpp at jdk8-b120 · openjdk/jdk · GitHub](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk8-b120/hotspot/src/share/vm/opto/graphKit.cpp#L556)

Comment: IMHO its impossible to give a formula that produces an exact count of executions. The count depends on how hot the code path is (how often is it executed), did the JIT compiler already kick in, what else is running, how often the exception is occuring (it seems to take longer if the exception happens more often) and possible many other factors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's indeed interesting why a small change causes such a big difference, however, the answer is not simple at all.

First off, a Java method may run in the interpreter or get JIT compiled. In the [tiered compilation mode](https://www.baeldung.com/jvm-tiered-compilation) (default), a method may be compiled multiple times with a different level of optimization.

`OmitStackTraceInFastThrow` optimization applies only to C2 compiled code (the highest tier). While a method is interpreted or C1 compiled, NPE will always have a stack trace regardless of the number of iterations. So the problem boils down to the question how fast the method gets compiled by C2. It's hard to predict the number though, because the [JIT compilation policy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35614237/3448419) is quite complex, involving many factors.

Let's consider a simplified example:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Uncomment the following line to see the difference
        // args.hashCode();

        int exceptionCount = 0;
        while (true) {
            try {
                ((Object) null).hashCode();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                exceptionCount++;
                if (e.getStackTrace().length == 0) {
                    System.out.println(exceptionCount);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It prints a number close to 115000, like in your test. The variance is explained by the fact that JIT compilation runs in the background, i.e. while a method is being compiled, it continues execution in the interpreter or at a lower tier.

To eliminate this variance, let's run it with background compilation disabled: `-Xbatch`.
Now the output becomes stable: **106496**. Why so?

1. `Test.main` starts running in the interpreter. Every 1024 loop iterations (2<sup>Tier0BackedgeNotifyFreqLog</sup> = 2<sup>10</sup> = 1024) the interpreter invokes JIT compilation policy to see if a method needs to be compiled.
2. As soon as the number of iterations exceeds 60000 (`-XX:Tier3BackEdgeThreshold`), the method is compiled at tier 3 (C1 with profiling). Given 1024 step, this happens after 1024*59 = 60416 iterations.
3. A method compiled at tier 3 invokes JIT policy much less often than the interpreter - more precisely, once in 8192 iterations (2<sup>Tier3BackedgeNotifyFreqLog</sup> = 2<sup>13</sup>).
4. After 40000 more loop iterations (`-XX:Tier4BackEdgeThreshold`), the method becomes eligible for recompilation at tier 4. In our case, this happens exactly after 8192*5 = 40960 iterations.
5. Initially, C2-compiled method doesn't include a fast path for throwing `NullPointerException`. The first invocation of a method on `null` object results in the uncommon trap, and the execution falls back to the interpreter.
6. Like in (1), the interpreter invokes the compilation policy again after 1024 loop iterations.
7. Compilation policy recognizes the method as hot and installs previously compiled C2 version, which immediately results in a new uncommon trap due to NPE.
8. Steps (5)-(7) are then repeated 4 times (`-XX:PerBytecodeTrapLimit`). After exceeding the limit, on the 5th attempt, the method is finally recompiled with a fast path for NPE. This "fast" NPE no longer has a stack trace.

The total number of loop iterations throughout the above life cycle is

```
60416 + 40960 + 5*1024 = 106496
```

Surprisingly, if I uncomment `args.hashCode()` call, the number of iterations will drop to **40961**. Why?

Even though the line looks unrelated, it affects the constant pool resolution. Both `args.hashCode()` and `((Object) null).hashCode()` refer to the same `CONSTANT_Methodref_info` in the constant pool. The first successful method invocation resolves this constant pool entry.

If a Methodref is unresolved and receiver is `null`, HotSpot JVM throws `NullPointerException` right during resolution of `invoke` instruction:

[image: unresolved.png]

But in the case of a resolved Methodref, JVM throws `NullPointerException` from a different place in the code. This another path records the fact of a thrown exception in the `MethodData` structure:

[image: resolved.png]

`MethodData` is a JVM structure that holds method's runtime profile to be used for JIT compilation. The presense of the profile makes JVM compile the method directly at tier 4 (because there is no need to collect profile at tier 3, if it was already collected in the interpreter).

In this case, when a number of loop iterations reaches 40000 (`-XX:Tier4BackEdgeThreshold`), the method is scheduled for compilation at tier 4. But since the feedback step is 1024 (2<sup>Tier0BackedgeNotifyFreqLog</sup>), the actual number of iterations before JIT compilation is 40*1024 = 40960.

#### Summary

Getting back to your original example. When `ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(2) == 0` is true, `hashCode()` is successfully resolved and executed. Subsequent NPEs are thrown from `invokevirtual` implementation, and as a side effect, JVM creates `MethodData` for the `main` method. When the number of loop iterations exceeds 40000 (half of them resulting in a normal call, and half in a thrown exception), the method gets compiled by C2 with `OmitStackTraceInFastThrow` optimization. Hence a little more than 20000 exceptions before the optimization.

On the contrary, `ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt() == 0` is almost never true. Therefore `hashCode()` call never succeeds: NPE is thrown while resolving the constant pool entry, and the entry remains unresolved. That's why the method is first compiled by C1 (after 60K iterations), then recompiled by C2 (after 40K more iterations). So the method throws more than 100K exceptions in total before `OmitStackTraceInFastThrow` optimization takes place.

Comment: You are a JVM expert.